# Store white space as the first character in text column in Laravel. Is it possible?

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am trying to store a space as string's first character but after the object is saved in db, the space is trimmed. The column type is text. Is it possible and if it is, how can i achieve that?

Update

First i tried to add the name of the input into the except array of TrimStrings Middleware. But it didn't worked.

The only way i achieved the result i want, is by comment out the whole TrimStrings Middleware in the Kernel.php. But i don't think that it is the appropriate way...

Comment: i guess this is coming from user input?

Comment: Yes it comes from a form